# Why does searching in a forked repo on github show no result while searching in the original repo does?

Tags: github

I forked a github repo. I want to search for something in the codes. But searching in the original repo shows matches while searching in my forked repo shows nothing. Why?

Comment: @Schwern Yes I just forked...sorry I haven't heard of indexing in git. What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Github doesn't allow searching in most forks. From [Searching in Forks](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-in-forks)...

> Forks are only indexed for code search when they have more stars than the parent repository. You will not be able to search the code in a fork that has less stars than its parent.

"Indexed" refers to creating a [search index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_indexing) so Github can do fast searches without having to read all the code.

I assume this has to with conserving resources to both build and store the search index.